# How to get Icecast server songs history

Tags: php, icecast

I am integrating live streaming from icecast server to my custom audio player using PHP. I need to show the recently played songs in the player. But I am unable to get it using the code below:

```
$XSPFurl = "http://IP:PORT/mount.xspf";
$XSPFans = file_get_contents($XSPFurl);
if ($XSPFans === false) {
    return 'error';
}
$stream = $this->getXSPF($XSPFans);
$song_pieces = explode(" - ", $stream['info']['title']);

$row[0]['song_name'] = isset($song_pieces[1]) ? $song_pieces[1] : '';
$row[0]['artist'] = isset($song_pieces[0]) ? $song_pieces[0] : '';
$row[0]['time'] = 'Currently';
return $row;

function getXSPF($data) {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
    $stream['info']['title'] = (string) $xml->trackList->track->title;
    $stream['info']['location'] = (string) $xml->trackList->track->location;
    preg_match_all('/^(.*):(.*)/m', (string) $xml->trackList->track->annotation, $matches);
    if (isset($matches[1]) && isset($matches[2])) {
        $t = @array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
        foreach ($t as $key => $val) {
            $fkey = str_replace(" ", "_", $key);
            $stream['info'][strtolower($fkey)] = trim($val);
        }
    }
    return $stream;
}
```

Also if I access `IP:PORT` on the browser it shows only current song in the web interface.

Can someone guide me on how I can get it done ?

Comment: it appears there is supporting code that you have not shared. What is `getXSPF`? Is this a method from your own class or from another library?

Comment: @RamRaider I have updated the code for getXSPF().

Answer (score 1):

The Icecast server does not have a built in function (unlike Shoutcast) to retrieve a playlist. One solution is to build a playlist yourself using the code you already have.

I would create a CRON job that fetches the server data every x seconds (maybe every 30 seconds).

First store the current structured song data in a database (or even a file/cache). Add a timestamp to log the first occurrence of the song. Then check if the newly fetched data differs from the old data, by comparing the old and new `$xml->trackList->track->title` for example.

If it differs, add a new entry into the Database/cache with the new timestamp. This way you can create a playlist with the time the song has played.

I'm currently in need of such a solution as I switched to Icecast because of the recent Shoutcast premium issues. As soon as I have created a decent solution I'll post it here.

**update**

First off, the following gist is no plug-n-play code, and created as a starting point for people with a base knowledge of PHP. If you just copy-paste this in your site it will probably not work.

I created a basic class for creating and retrieving a JSON playlist from an Icecast server. It fetches the current song from the server, checks if it has been stored already. If not, it adds an entry in the database.

To start, create a table in your database with the necessary fields:

```
CREATE TABLE `now_playing` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `playedat` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `artist` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coverImage` mediumtext,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

To use it you will probably want to create a cronjob that fetches the song info every minute or so using `$songInfoClass->fetchSongInfo()`. Then in the endpoint where you output your JSON feed, you simply echo `$songInfoClass->getPlaylist()` and it fetches the latest results from the database. The playist length has been set to 20 items, but you can change this in the class properties.

In addition, you can add a daily cron to cleanup the playlist at the end of the day. It depends on how long you want your playlist to be.

You can view the gist here:
https://gist.github.com/sanderdewijs/5eb38e4f4ce7fca631fb44a182e2b97a

Answer (score 1):

You can read the playlist log file and parse filtering for desired mount point.

DOC for logging: https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-trunk/config_file/#logging-settings

Sample tail of log file for playlist:

```
server:~$ sudo tail -f /var/log/icecast2/playlist.icecast.log
29/Jun/2021:14:14:40 -0400|/grandefm|0|Hawai - Maluma
29/Jun/2021:14:17:55 -0400|/grandefm|1|Lean On (feat M And DJ Snake) - Major Lazer
29/Jun/2021:14:21:10 -0400|/grandefm|1|Grande FM 92,1 Mhz - DouradosMS
29/Jun/2021:14:26:25 -0400|/grandefm|1|Big In Japan - ALPHAVILLE
29/Jun/2021:14:29:55 -0400|/grandefm|1|Grande FM 92,1 Mhz - DouradosMS
29/Jun/2021:14:30:10 -0400|/grandefm|1|Tarzan Boy - Baltimora
29/Jun/2021:14:34:40 -0400|/grandefm|1|Grande FM 92,1 Mhz - DouradosMS
29/Jun/2021:14:34:58 -0400|/grandefm|1|Cheirosa - Jorge e Mateus
29/Jun/2021:14:37:40 -0400|/grandefm|2|Prudente - Thiaguinho
29/Jun/2021:14:40:55 -0400|/grandefm|2|Grande FM 92,1 Mhz - DouradosMS
29/Jun/2021:14:45:10 -0400|/grandefm|2|Paradise - Meduza Part. Dermot Kennedy
```