# Icecast song history

Tags: php, wordpress, icecast

I am developing a radio streaming website on wordpress. I found the script below that should be able to do the job. But I am unable to figure out how to implement this script in my website so that it will show a short playlist history. Could someone perhaps enlighten me on what changes I have to make to the script?

My icecast stream url is this:
http://server-26.stream-server.nl:8812/stream

Thanks in advance.

Milan

```
<?php

    /**
     * Class IceCastPlaylist
     * See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60502076/how-to-get-icecast-server-songs-history/60798774#60798774 for context
     * 
     * This class can be used as follows:
     * global $wpdb
     * $playlistClass = new IceCastPlaylist($wpdb);
     * $playlistClass->fetchSongInfo();
     * $playlist = $songInfoClass->getPlaylist();
     * header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
     * echo $playlist;
     * die();
     */
    class IceCastPlaylist {
    
        /**
         * @var wpdb
         */
        protected $db;
    
        /**
         * @var string
         */
        protected $table = '[replace with playlist table]';
    
    
        /**
         * Replace this with your server URL
         * @var string
         */
        protected $songDataUrl = 'http://server-26.stream-server.nl:8812/stream';
    
        /**
         * @var string
         */
        protected $albumCoverUrl = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?entity=musicTrack&term=';
    
        /**
         * Replace this with your storage path
         * @var string
         */
        protected $albumCoverPath = '[absolute_path_to_cover_images_folder e.g /media/covers/]';
    
        /**
         * Replace with your site URL
       * Most of the time you will want to set the URL to the site dynamically, 
       * so we do this in the constructor
         */
        protected $siteUrl = 'https://stamcafe.compra.nl';
    
        /**
         * Replace this with the desired length of your playlist
         * @var int
         */
        protected $playlistLength = 10;
    
        /**
         * IceCastPlaylist constructor.
         * In this case, I used WordPress wpdb, but it can be replaced with another DB instance
       * When using something else than wpdb, the query functions will need to be adjusted
         *
         * @param $db
         */
        public function __construct(wpdb $db) {
            $this->db = $db;
        // If you need to set the site URL via a function, you can set it here in the constructor
            $this->siteUrl = get_site_url() . '/wp-content/media/covers/';
        }
    
        public function getPlaylist() {
            $result = $this->db->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$this->table} as songs ORDER BY `songs`.`id` DESC LIMIT {$this->playlistLength}");
            return json_encode($result);
        }
    
        /**
         * [
         *  'playedat' => 'H:i',
         *  'title' => 'title',
         *  'artist' => 'bla',
         *  'coverImage' => 'linkToCoverArt',
         *  'created_at' => 'Y-m-d',
         * ]
         * @param array $entry
         */
        public function storeEntry(array $entry) {
            $this->db->insert($this->table, $entry);
        }
    
        /**
         * @return mixed
         * @throws Exception
         */
        public function fetchSongInfo() {
            $rawData = file_get_contents($this->songDataUrl);
            $now = new DateTime('now');
            if(!$rawData) {
                throw new Exception('Error retrieving song data');
            }
    
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($rawData);
            $titleArtist = preg_split("/\s-\s/", (string) $xml->trackList->track->title);
    
            if($this->isNewSong($titleArtist[1])) {
    
                $stream['playedAt'] = $now->format('H:i');
                $stream['title'] = $titleArtist[1];
                $stream['artist'] = $titleArtist[0];
                $stream['coverImage'] = $this->getCoverArt($xml->trackList->track->title);
                $stream['created_at'] = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    
                $this->storeEntry($stream);
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Use in your daily cleanup cron
         */
        public function dailyCleanup() {
            $this->db->query("TRUNCATE TABLE {$this->table}");
        }
    
        /**
         * @param string $title
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        private function isNewSong(string $title) {
            $result = $this->db->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$this->table} as songs ORDER BY `songs`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1");
            if(empty($result)) {
                return true;
            }
    
            return $result[0]->title !== $title;
        }
    
        /**
         * Take the raw 'songtitle - artist' and try to find cover art
         * @param string $title
         *
         * @return string|null
         */
        private function getCoverArt(string $title) {
            $itunesData = wp_remote_get($this->albumCoverUrl . urlencode($title), array(
                'timeout' => 45,
                'redirection' => 5,
                'httpversion' => '1.0',
                'blocking' => true,
                'headers' => array(
                    'accept-encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
                    'pragma' => 'no-cache',
                    'accept-language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                    'user-agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36',
                    'accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8'
                ),
                'cookies' => array(),
            ));
    
            $songInfo = json_decode(trim(wp_remote_retrieve_body($itunesData)));
            $imageHash = '';
            if(isset($songInfo->results[0])) {
                $coverImage = str_replace('100x100bb.jpg', '', $songInfo->results[0]->artworkUrl100);
                $imageHash = md5($title) . '.jpg';
                if(!file_exists($this->albumCoverPath . $imageHash) && $coverImage !== '') {
                    $img = file_get_contents($coverImage . '200x200bb.jpg');
                    file_put_contents($this->albumCoverPath . $imageHash, $img);
                }
            }
    
            return (empty($imageHash)) ? null :  $this->siteUrl . $imageHash;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just create a page template and add the code that's in the commented out section under "This calss can be used as follows". Create a page, choose the template. Should be good to go.